# How to animate a React state value change when linked to an input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-hooks, gsap

I'm building a React application and I have a form with a number of different fields. Each field has two forms of input: a text input and a range input. In the current version, they both have the same piece of state as their value and the same set function in their onChange, keeping them synced.

However, when a new value is entered on one of the inputs, I would like the other to animate the change in itself, rather than changing instantly.

For example, if the text input for the 'motor-power' field is currently at 1, the range input will be all the way to the left. If I type 10 into the text input, it should immediately change. The range input should then slide up from 1 to 10 over 200ms or so.

There are plenty of ways to animate objects, elements or non-state values, but I'm struggling to implement the behaviour for a value stored in React's state.

I tried using gsap.to(), but it seems to cause issues when it manually changes a state value.

I also tried writing a custom useAnimatedState hook that uses setInterval internally and tracks two states, one for the text input and one for the slider input. It became a bit of a mess, and although it is along the right lines, it breaks when the range input is moved too fast and doesn't correctly change the slider value when changing the text input.

```
  function useAnimatedState(initialValue, animationInterval = 15) {
    const [textState, setTextState] = useState(initialValue);
    const [sliderState, setSliderState] = useState(initialValue);

    function setAnimatedState(type, value) {
      const state = type === "text" ? textState : sliderState;
      const otherState = type === "text" ? sliderState : textState;
      const setState = type === "text" ? setTextState : setSliderState;
      const setOtherState = type === "text" ? setSliderState : setTextState;

      const isIncrease = value > state;
      const isDecrease = value < state;

      let step = 0;

      setState(value);

      let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (isIncrease && step < state - otherState) {
          step++;
          setOtherState((prevState) => prevState + 1);
        } else if (isDecrease && step < otherState - state) {
          step++;
          setOtherState((prevState) => prevState - 1);
        } else {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          intervalId = null;
          step = 0;
        }
      }, animationInterval);
    }

    return [textState, sliderState, setAnimatedState];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to use useRef in this case because the state setter function would trigger a component re-render. The slide's states stored in ref.current can be updated based on the input's states, which are tracked using the useEffect dependency array

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).